# Get time of multiple location like google using Google API. PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Get time  of multiple location like google  using Google API. PHP, i
searched everywhere on internet but im getting solution for two
locations only,i need solution for multiple location time like google
map in php. Help me anyone please

```
$from = "Więckowskiego 72, Łódź";
$to = "Gazowa 1, Łódź";

$from = urlencode($from);
$to = urlencode($to);

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);

$time = 0;
$distance = 0;

foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $time += $road->duration->value;
    $distance += $road->distance->value;
}

echo "To: ".$data->destination_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "From: ".$data->origin_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "Time: ".$time." seconds";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Distance: ".$distance." meters";
```

Above solution is working for me fine but i need the same solution for
multiple locations to get the between multiple locations like :

locations:

```
From Location :anna nagar.
Points :thiruvanmiyur.
Points  :guindy.
To Location :ashok nagar.
```

i need to get time and kilometers for above multiple locations

Answer (score 1):

Do you must use an API to retrieve time at different locations? or you just want the end result?

If you can safely assume that your server's locate time is accurate (you can set up an NTP client for that), and that you trust your PHP library for the most part, then you don't need the APIs to get local logical times.

What's the time in Berlin right now?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date("g:ia"); //Time in Berlin
```

What about London?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date("g:ia"); //Time in London, same as UTC without DS
```

Comment: im asking travelling distance time and kilometers between 4 or five locations ,i mean multiple locations

Comment: I did this before and used Google's Directions API. It supports all the routeable locations.

Comment: If you have 4 locations, A, B, C and D, the Directions API will give you the travel distance and estimated travel time between any two points, so you'll have to call it for A-B, B-C and C-D and add them up. The detailed response contains legs, or segments of a route, each containing Distance and Duration.

Comment: i need the correct caculation ,im not able to get,for example, if your going to any shop from your home right, how long it will take to reach the shop from your home that may be 30 mins thats the time,again if your going from that shop to another shop then it will take another 30 mins right ,so the over all time in 30 mins +30 mins= 1 hour right , thats the over all solution im asking riht ,hope you will understand my problem right

Comment: Can you not ask the API to return the time between Home and Shop 1, and then then time between Shop1 and Shop2, and add them up. I think you are trying to find an API to do that but it's more reliable to make multiple calls. If I still don't understand you, I'll just give up. Sorry I really tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202540/discussion-between-sss-s-and-ian-heisler).